# Insert 8 rows into 8 columns

Tags: mysql

i am just getting the result from a query like this

```
user_id
108
183
172
129
158
178
117
104
```

and i want the result in this format

```
m1    m2   m3   m4   m5   m6   m7   m8
108  183  172  129  158  178  117   104
```

can anybody help me

Comment: -1, now go and try something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: (That's my upvote, that has to be one of the best comments I've seen in awhile from an OP.)

Comment: @MURTUZA007 read about pivot table

Comment: Please add an explanation of your specific use case requirements, your table structure and current query to your question. If you expect people to make the effort to help you, you need to put some effort into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get a similar resultset :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( user_id ) FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```

Otherwise if you want to create a new column for each row in the result set you can go with a CASE, but the values or the ranges of values must be hard coded :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN user_id = 108 THEN user_id ELSE 0 END AS m1, CASE WHEN user_id = 183 THEN user_id ELSE 0 END AS m2, ...
```

Or by ranges :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN user_id > 100  AND user_id < 150 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) ELSE 0 END AS m1, CASE WHEN user_id > 150 AND user_id < 200 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) ELSE 0 END AS m2, ...
```

Comment: Care to attach example output? :)

Comment: It will show the output as an array separated by commas, to enforce different column names for each result i think the only way is a CASE ...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. This is probably not what the OP wants :)

Comment: I think the only way to achieve what op's want is an hard coded CASE, but it is hard coded ...

Answer (score 3):

try below mentioned link: 
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78